# Linking to a library that links to a lib I'm already linking to

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking, one-definition-rule

Forgive the convoluted title.

The setup for this problem is as follows:

I have an open source lib I have built into a bunch of .libs (VTK if you were curious)

I have a library that uses the aforementioned static lib. Lets call it Lib A.

I also have an application that uses the aforementioned library (i.e. VTK) AND also uses Lib A.

During build time, I get a linker error telling me that a function called from Lib A has already been defined in a library that is linked to the application (error: LNK2005)

Any ideas on how to fix this short of switching everything to be dynamically linked?

Comment: You can't really fix that, either 1. Don't link to VTK in your main app. 2. link to VTK dynamically 3. Don't include VTK in Lib A

Comment: So if I link VTK to Lib A and link Lib A to the main app, would that work?

Comment: Yes, as long as the whole of VTK is included in LibA. Though, you seem to be using MSVC, I'm not sure how to reliably do that with MSVC, possibly with the /OPT:NOREF linker option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Lib A was using the statically built version of VTK while the main app was linking against a dynamic-linked version of VTK.

So the problem really was that I had the same functions defined in a .lib and a .dll which caused the linker to fail.